# MySQL prepareStatement Batch slow

Tags: java, mysql, windows

I have the following code to insert rows in a MySQL table:

```
String sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO test_perf_table ( id, name) VALUES ( ?, ?);";
PreparedStatement sqlInsertSt = connection.prepareStatement(sqlInsert);

for (int i = 0; i < SETSIZE; i++) {
    sqlInsertSt.setInt( 1, ids[i]);
    sqlInsertSt.setString( 2, names[i]);
    sqlInsertSt.addBatch();
}
int[] updateCounts = sqlInsertSt.executeBatch();
```

The problem is i am only archiving 21 transactions per second which is really low, was expecting something 10x faster.

So my question is, does my code need to improved or maybe is the database configuration problem ?

The MySQL server is running @localhost, in Win8, using the my-large.ini default config, using mysql-connector-java-5.1.13 driver.

Not sure but i think the engine is myisam since i did not specify anything

edit:

```
CREATE TABLE test_perf_table (
    id INT,
    name VARCHAR(20) 
);
```

Comment: How about a `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, which may reveal some important details.  Also, isn't your `for` loop overwriting the parameters each time?

Comment: no each loop adds a statment to the batch if i am not wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just dealt with this recently.

The thing that will make the biggest difference is adding the parameter `rewriteBatchedStatements=true` to your jdbc connection url.

You may also see a performance improvement by executing executeBatch() in a transaction.

Comment: Excellent. Was that just with rewriteBatchedStatements, or did you need the transaction to get that performance?

Comment: on my original code i forgot to setAutoCommit(false) however i could only archive 5k TPS
i needed atleast 20k TPS doing multiple batchs with avg 10k per batch, rewriteBatchedStatements boosted up to 50k TPS